# Как найти угол между горизонтом и направляющей прямой?

Tags: c++

Нужно найти косинус угла, ещё лучше сразу угол между горизонтом(powerdown) и направляющей прямой(power)

```
#include <graphics.h> 
#include <cmath> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h> 

using namespace std; 
int radius = 30, cx, cy, i=0, k=0;   
void powers() {
    double power, powerdown,anglecos;
    POINT p;
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    power = pow(p.x*p.x+p.y*p.y, 0.5);
    powerdown = pow(p.x*p.x+getmaxy()/1.2*getmaxy()/1.2, 0.5);
    anglecos = (p.x*p.x+p.y*getmaxy()/1.2)/power*powerdown;
} 

void background() {
    setfillstyle(1,11);
    bar(0, 0, getmaxx(), getmaxy()/1.2);
    setfillstyle(1,2);
    bar(0, getmaxy()/1.2, getmaxx(), getmaxy());
} 

void vect() {
    POINT p;
    float a;
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    /*(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON)?"YES":"NO")
    "\tLEFT: "<<(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)?"YES":"NO")*/
    // p.x p.y
    if(p.y>getmaxy()/1.2)
    {
        a=getmaxy()/1.2;
    }
    else 
    {
        a=p.y-35;
    }

    setcolor(14);
    line(0,getmaxy()/1.2, p.x-3,a);
}
void lined(int a) {
    int obert1=1;
    POINT p;
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    if(p.y>getmaxy()/1.2)
    {
        a=getmaxy()/1.2;
    }
    else 
    {
        a=p.y-35;
    }

    cx = getmaxx()/2;
    cy = getmaxy()/2;
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)!=0)
    {
        const int obert1 = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        obert1=0;
    }

    if(k==1) 
    {
        obert1=1;
    }

    if(obert1 == 1)     
    {
        setcolor(0);
        setlinestyle(0, 0, 5);
        line(p.x-3-radius*cos(i*M_PI/180), a-radius*sin(i*M_PI/180), p.x-3 + radius*cos(i*M_PI/180), a + radius*sin(i*M_PI/180));
        k=1;
    }
    else if(k==0)
    {
        setcolor(0);
        setlinestyle(0, 0, 5);
        line(p.x-3-radius*cos(0*M_PI/180), a-radius*sin(0*M_PI/180), p.x-3 + radius*cos(0*M_PI/180), a + radius*sin(0*M_PI/180));
    }
    delay(1);
} 

void draw(float speed) {
    for(i = 0;; i+=speed)
    {
        background();
        vect();
        powers();
        lined(i);
        delay(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int gdriver = DETECT, gmode, errorcode;
    float speed;
    initwindow(920, 800);
    cout<<"Vvedit kutovu shvidkist"<<endl;     cin>>speed;
    system("cls");
    while(1)
    {
        draw(speed);
    }
    closegraph(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Где у вас в коде прямые? Почему вы называете `double power, powerdown` "прямыми"?

Answer (score 2):

Текст нечитабелен, но предположу, что имеется вектор направления прямой. Вот его надо нормализовать - привести к единичной длине делением компонентов на длину вектора, и выполнить скалярное произведение этого единичного вектора с единичным вектором горизонта.

Результат - косинус угла между векторами.

Comment: та можно и без нормализации, вроде бы

Comment: @raviga Можно, если вектора единичные уже, либо через atan2 с использованием ещё векторного произведения.